# How to see the order of shared library loading

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, elf

Given an ELF binary or shared object, how can I most easily see the order in which the needed shared libraries will be loaded?

Are they loaded in the order they are listed by `readelf -d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I most easily see the order in which the needed shared libraries will be loaded?

Use `LD_DEBUG`:

```
LD_DEBUG=files /bin/ls
13444:
13444:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by who [0]
...
13444:     file=libnss_files.so.2 [0];  needed by who [0]
...
```

For more info man ld.so.

> Are they loaded in the order they are listed by readelf -d?

Not necessarily e.g. it will be influenced by preloading (`LD_PRELOAD`, `/etc/ld.so.preload`).

Answer (score 5):

Using `LD_DEBUG=files` allows you to see in which order the libraries are searched, *and* in which order they are initialized. The latter may be different from the former.

> Are they loaded in the order they are listed by `readelf -d`

Depends on what you mean by "loaded". A library is "fully loaded" once it's initializer returned.

Under that definition, no: the order of `NEEDED` dependencies listed in `readelf -d` and the order of loading are not the same.

Consider `a.out` which depends on `libA.so` and `libB.so`:

```
readelf -d a.out | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libA.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libB.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

And further, `libA.so` itself depends on `libC.so` and `libD.so`:

```
readelf -d libA.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libC.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libD.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

The order in which the libraries are searched:

```
LD_DEBUG=files ./a.out |& grep 'needed by'
     49169: file=libA.so [0];  needed by ./a.out [0]
     49169: file=libB.so [0];  needed by ./a.out [0]
     49169: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ./a.out [0]
     49169: file=libC.so [0];  needed by ./libA.so [0]
     49169: file=libD.so [0];  needed by ./libA.so [0]
```

The order in which libraries are "fully loaded":

```
 LD_DEBUG=files ./a.out |& grep 'calling init'
     69038: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     69038: calling init: ./libD.so
     69038: calling init: ./libC.so
     69038: calling init: ./libB.so
     69038: calling init: ./libA.so
```

Other factors that could affect loading order:

1. `LD_PRELOAD` or `/etc/ld.so.preload`.
2. Any of the libraries can perform `dlopen` in its initializer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In particular, knowing that initialisation order isn't necessarily the same as library load order is useful for me (and probably for others in the future).

Comment: And for context, the reason I ask this is that we have an ordering condition on our library initialisers, but they don't have a set priority. I wanted to make sure I understood the problem before I come up with a fix.