# Lifetime of a static variable in a local scope in a shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-variables

I have a question on destruction time of static variables in a local scope.
Suppose we have a shared library named `plugin` that is used by another shared library named `rt`.
Also, there is an application that uses the `rt` library. All dependencies are explicit. No `dlopen`/`LibraryLoad`.

```cpp
// libplugin.so | plugin.dll
namespace plugin {
struct storage {
    storage(int sz) : bytes(sz) {}
    ~storage() = default;
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
};
}
```

```cpp
// librt.so | rt.dll
namespace rt {
std::unordered_map<int, plugin::storage> &cached_storages() {
    static std::unordered_map<int, plugin::storage> instance;
    return instance;
}

void do_somework() {
    auto &storages = cached_storages();
    // do some work with storages
}
}
```

```cpp
// User's app
int main() {
    rt::do_somework();
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, is the order of unloading the `rt` and `plugin` libraries strictly defined on Linux? On Windows?
My concern is that the `plugin` library can be unloaded before the `rt` library hence the destructor of the static `instance` variable will crash.

Comment: Maybe this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/40637303/1741542

Comment: You seem to be asking whether shared libraries are horribly broken. The answer is no, they are quite usable. You can have a static variable that refers to code from a different shared library, there is absolutely nothing to worry about.